# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in PHP 5.4.16, Windows8, Apache

Tags: php, com, doc

i have tried to search this in stack overflow database and everyone of them have a similar answer for this problem, but it still does not seem to work.

problem: I am trying to write a simple script for converting the doc file into an HTML output for a job portal. Where user access its personal profile, there a link is to be provided to see the previous uploaded cv[Doc file] in HTML format.

SYSTEM CONFIGURATION- using WAMP2.4 , PHP 5.4.16, Apache 2.4.4 on windows8 32-bit

also, in windows8 by default .net framework 4.5 is already installed, which is required to invoke ms word COM object

Now,according to the PHP MANUAL COM installation requirements:

1.COM functions are only available for the Windows version of PHP.

2.Net support requires PHP 5 and the .Net runtime.

Part of PHP script code:

```
// create an instance for the word application
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate application object");
```

So executing the script it, gives the FATAL error : Class 'COM' not found

As per most of the solutions,

Have already edited : php.ini file with

```
[COM_DOT_NET]
extension = php_com_dotnet_dll
```

also checked the extension dir , which is set to

```
extension_dir = "F:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.16/ext/"
enable_dl = On
```

enable dl is also set

Restarted the apache server, also tired after system reboot, still same error appears!!

Getting no clue to fix it,  also is there a better way to get an HTML output from DOC file without using COM objects, as i want to make a script that does not need any extra plugin to fix it

Or using PhpLiveDocx is the best solution ??

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled php.ini extension setting:

> ```
> [COM_DOT_NET]
> extension = php_com_dotnet_dll
> ```

This works:

```
[PHP_COM_DOTNET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```